# ReactNative scrollToEnd() on FlatList - Functional Component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Am trying to implement a chat app using `ReactNative`. The problem am facing is, after new item is added to the `FlatList`, am trying to scroll the FlatList items to the bottom so that the newly added message is visible.

When I checked the documentation, I can see a method called [scrollToEnd()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoend). But not sure how to use it as am following the Functional Component style of coding. Because when I googled, I can see examples where it uses the `ref` in a Class Component style coding.

But couldn't find how to use it in Functional Component!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `useRef`

```js
// I hope you don't mind the typescript
import {useRef} from 'react';
import {FlatList} from 'react-native';

export const Comp = () => {
    const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList<any>>();

    // however you detect new items
    flatListRef?.current?.scrollToEnd();

    return (
        <FlatList
            data={[]}
            renderItem={() => null}
            ref={flatListRef}
        />
    );
}
```

But I think if you use `inverted={true}` on the flat list, it should snap to the top, or better bottom (**I think**).

Comment: Thank you. When I used the `useRef`, I was able to scroll the contents down to the end automatically. But it shows it only when the keyboard in my `TextInput` is closed. Instead when I used the `inverted={true}`, the above keyboard issue was resolved. Is there anyway to resolve that keyboard blocking issue when the `ref` way is used?

Comment: You are saying that it is not scrolling when you are typing/are focused on the input? I have never encountered that, I will see if I can reproduce that.

Comment: It scrolls, but it won't be visible when the keyboard is still open (typing/focused) in the InputBox (situated at the bottom of the screen). But when the keyboard is closed, I can see the scrolled to the end of the screen. Issue is because of the opened keyboard. But if I used the `inverted` property, there's no issues.

Comment: Is the keyboard overlaying the scroll list?

Comment: Yeah it seems to be overlaying

Comment: Also, for the `inverted={true}` technique, the top padding seems to be not working in the FlatList. Any workarounds?

Comment: Can you join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218472/room-for-elias-and-vpp-man ?

Comment: I have upvoted you as a token of appreciation for the time spend on chat, trying to figure out the issue. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For typescript you can use just:

```
const listRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);
```

and in your code you just need to check if your ref is exist:

```
listRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: yourIndex})
```